# Why isn't my picturebox animation working as expected (C# Windows Form Application)?

Tags: c#, loops, width, logic, picturebox

I'm making a simple memory game for school, using c# and a windows form application. The cards are created as pictureboxes and I'm trying to animate the flipping of cards, by reducing and increasing the width of the pictureboxes. Using a for loop I managed to make somewhat of an animation which works as I would expect, the card slowly shrinks in width. However when I try to reverse the code it seems to wait the full duration of the animation after which the card just pops to full width.

I call the following function from a click event, passing the picturebox that was clicked:

```
private void AnimateCard(PictureBox picture)
{
    //part working as I would expect:
    Size defaultSize = picture.Size;
    Size temp = defaultSize;

    for (int w = defaultSize.Width; w != 0; w -= 2)
    {
        temp.Width = w;
        picture.Size = temp;
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    //here would be where I change the images inside the picturesboxes

    //the part not working as I would expect:
    for (int w = temp.Width; w != defaultSize.Width; w += 2)
    {
        temp.Width = w;
        picture.Size = temp;
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

}
```

I'll be happy with any suggestion to either fix my error or animate my 'card flip' some other way (within a windows form application!)

Comment: I know you said you need it in WinForms, but seriously, this isn't what WinForms was designed for. You should *seriously* consider WPF. I'll take a look and see if I can find your bug though.

Comment: I'm doing this project together with a classmate and we are currently not in a position to start over. The animation is not required for the game which is why we used a winform in the first place.

I hope you'll find what I can't :D

Comment: I doubt that the ui refreshes while the thread sleeps. insert a refresh before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems with your code:

- Never compare for equality lightly; use defensive style programming and write `<` or `<=`.  In this case testing for inequality actually does amount to a test for equality! Your code will fail if the `Picturebox`'s `Width` is an odd number!
- Don't use `for` unless you have a counter or have an enumerator; if you want to use a condition use `while`. This is about readability.
- The (other) real hard problem is that the `PictureBox` needs a `Refresh` for the growing part. Best include it in the shrinking part as well..

---

```
Size defaultSize = pictureBox1.Size;
Size temp = defaultSize;

for (int w = defaultSize.Width; w > 0; w -= 2)
{
    temp.Width = w;
    pictureBox1.Size = temp;
    pictureBox1.Refresh();   // may be optional
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}


for (int w = temp.Width; w < defaultSize.Width; w += 2)
{
    temp.Width = w;
    pictureBox1.Size = temp;
    pictureBox1.Refresh();  // is necessary
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

I'll leave the conversion to a do while loop to you..

Comment: I understand the safety of using < and > however in this case I know the size is always the same, I probably should've used constant values instead of variables or <>. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The two issues are that __you__ know __today__, but __who__ knows __tomorrow__? (Another issue reason may be if your teacher does a code review. I would subtract points..) good luck

Comment: at some point I actually had the < and > in there but I reversed it when I found out it wasn't the bug, DOH. how would I use a while loop? while(w+=2 < defaultSize.Witdh){}

Comment: Close. More ways than one. The terse style you used could be written as `int w = defaultSize.Width; while ( (w -= 2) > 0){...} .. while ( (w += 2) < defaultSize.Width)  {..`

Comment: how would you write it?

Comment: probably put the increment into the code block. I like/try to write code like I write prose: readable. Which leads to maintainability. A line saved is not really a line where nothing can go wrong, more likely it's a line you can't debug..

Answer (score 1):

You have unknowingly entered the realm of threading and locking up the user interface.

If you just want to make it work then after your Thread.Sleep(10)s put (the much dreaded):

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

Doing that will allow the form to process events and update and paint the user interface.

You could also use a timer with a count down form scope variable to make it seem like its happening  that would be less hokey (yet still a bit hokey) heres how.

```
    bool postHiding;       
    private int defaultsize = picture.size;
    private void AnimateCard(PictureBox picture)
    {
        postHiding = false;
        Timer1.Interval(12);
        Timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object obj, Eventargs e)
    {
        Size temp = defaultSize;
        if (!postHiding)
        {
            picture.Size.Width -=2;
            //This indicates the shrinking process is over
            if (picture.Size <= 0)
            {
                postHiding = true;
            }
        } else // We are now revealing the other side of the card
        {
            picture.Size.Width += 2;

            if (picture.Size >= defaultsize)
            {
                //Animation is Over
                Timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```